# Is there a way to choose a villager's profession after spawning it?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

When spawning a villager with a spawn egg, if the villager spawns with a profession, there is no way to reconvert them to another job.

Is there a command to specifically spawn a butcher for example? Or an unemployed villager?

Keep in mind that I am on Bedrock Edition.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, if you have no other workstations in the area he will eventually change professions according to the workstation you have in place, the more tied down to a profession this villager is (meaning the more you've traded with that villager while it had said profession, the longer it can take for it to start looking for a new profession upon destroying their workstation) the rules for the profession a villager has is: one villager per workstation, so as long as you either have no other workstation (as I mentioned) or all the other workstations are taken and there is an un-hired villager you can choose it's profession.